# Dates as integers? How to convert from integer to date again?

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, finance, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to do an analysis of the BTC price here in Brazil, and compare it with other 4 countries..

So I've found [quandl](http://www.quandl.com) and downloaded their .csv data for both countries.

> Each .csv has 6 columns:
>
> 1. Date
> 2. 24h.Average
> 3. Ask
> 4. Bid
> 5. Last
> 6. Total.Volume

Well, I'm trying to make a new table with:

1. `BTCBRL$Date`
2. `BTCBRL$Last`
3. `BTCUSD$Last`
4. `BTCCNY$Last`
5. `BTCEUR$Last`

So I wrote:

```
lastPrices <- cbind(BTCBRL$Date, BTCBRL$Last, BTCUSD$Last, BTCCNY$Last, BTCEUR$Last)
```

But then my date that once was `2015-07-05`, just became `656`..

What's an efficient to deal with it? Preferably overwriting it in the same table..

Comment: Recommendations for packages are considered off-topic. If you have a specific programming question, better to ask that directly rather than ask for packages.

Comment: The important point to learn is that `cbind` creates an R matrix which then destroys the attributes for Dates and factors. The `cbind.data.frame` function would not be so destructive , and furthermore you could not access a matrix column with `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data.frame()` rather than `cbind()` if you want to preserve mixed types (ie have both dates and numeric values). The latter returns a matrix and a matrix can only hold a single atomic data type so it converts everything to numeric.

Comment: or `cbind.data.frame`

Comment: Sure @rawr, that would work. But since we're building a new data object rather than adding to a new one, `data.frame` makes more logical sense to me.

Comment: thanks! it worked! 
if my data only contains numbers, why should i use matrix() instead of data.frame()?

Comment: But your data contains dates which are not numbers. Using a matrix makes it easier to perform matrix math. Matrices also a "lighter-weight" container. But they have more limitations.